# Electric toothbrush charging time

Tags: batteries, charging, time, nimh

I replaced my old Ni-Cd 1.2 volt sub-c battery (1500 mah) from my electric toothbrush to a new Ni-MH battery 1.2 volt sub-c (3800 mah). I looked inside the toothbrush and it look like there is no circuit that control the charging time of the battery, meaning I could overcharge my battery if I do not unplug the battery charger. My battery charger specification is:

Manufacturer: ROTA-DENT

Model Number: GS-270

Input Voltage: 120V AC 60Hz  5W

Output:  1.45V DC 120mA

My question is: How much time should I let my battery charger work when my battery is empty and or is there a way to know when the battery if fully charge?

Thanks

P.s.: There is no visual aid on the appliance that give information (no l.e.d. light indicator, nothing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NiMH battery charged at 1/10 of its capacity takes about 14 hours, that is a 1000mAh battery charged at 100mA needs about 14 hours.

If your charger current is indeed 120mA then it will take \$ \frac{3800mAh}{120mA} \times 1.4 \approx 44 hours \$

Charging a NiMH battery this way is not the best (plus the specified current is very low for the capacity you have selected) but I see no alternative.

For more info regarding the NiCD and NiMH batteries you can read:
http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_nickel_based_batteries
http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_nickel_metal_hydride

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be very slow to charge. The other alternative would be to change the battery charger with a higher charging rate. Anyway it's an electric toothbrush, there is no rush. Is my comprehension right 120 mA = 120 mAh ?

Comment: I think with a higher charging rate there will be to much heat production and not enough dissipation. The wire gauge is the same and the appliance is pretty much seal from water.

Comment: @user35374 Yes, 120mA is 120mAh but that doesn't mean that a 1200mAh battery will charge in 10 hours with that current. As I wrote the charge with a current of 1/10 of the capacity of the battery will need about 14 hours

Comment: the efficiency loss is 40%?

Comment: @user35374 A typical charge rate is 1/10 with no heat problems

Comment: @user35374 http://www.powerstream.com/NiMH.htm `The coulometric charging efficiency of nickel metal hydride batteries is typically 66%, meaning that you must put 150 amp hours into the battery for every 100 amp hours you get out. The faster you charge the worse this gets. `